# ActionScript drag limit, backwards?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an application where a user uploads an image and then transforms it by clicking, dragging and using a resize bar. But my client has asked me to limit where the user can drag to, this is not a problem except I need the limits the opposite way around to what would be considered normal.

So where I have startDrag(false, new Rectangle...) that works just fine, but what I need is to let the user be able to drag outside of the boundaries and not have white space on the inside of the flash file.

What I mean by this is say I have a 500px wide flash file and an image inside it which I'm carelessly dragging around. If the images right hand edge (if I drag left) hits 500px it stops dragging and does not allow them to pull it any further left.

I truly hope I've explained this well, any guidance would be awesome!

**Below is the code I currently have for the drag events.**

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
public function startImageDrag (e:MouseEvent):void {
        mousePos['x'] = e.target.mouseX;
        mousePos['y'] = e.target.mouseY;
        imageDraggable.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function ():void {});
        photoapp.cStage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveImage);
        photoapp.cStage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endImageDrag);
    }
    //The type is wildcarded because I have this hooked to MOUSE_LEAVE too
    public function endImageDrag (e:*):void {
        photoapp.cStage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveImage);
        photoapp.cStage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startImageDrag);
    }

    public function moveImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
        //Get the offset of the current mouse position over the image
        var
            //The mouse position on the stage
            sxOff:Number = photoapp.cStage.mouseX,
            syOff:Number = photoapp.cStage.mouseY,
            //The position on which the mouse down event was on the image
            reX:Number = sxOff - mousePos['x'],
            reY:Number = syOff - mousePos['y'],
            //The iamge object
            i:DisplayObject = imageDraggable;

        //Move the image
        if (/*I have no idea now...*/) {
            imageDraggable.x = reX;
        }
        if (iY) {
            imageDraggable.y = reY;
        }

        event.updateAfterEvent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// this code will limit the movement to 100 pixels to the right
var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0,0,100,0)
imageDraggable.startDrag( false,bounds );
```

[EDIT]
Maybe this will help you some more understanding

```
var boundsWidth:Number  = stage.stageWidth  - pictureHolderMC.width );
var boundsHeight:Number = stage.stageHeight - pictureHolderMC.height );
var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, boundsWidth, boundsHeight);
pictureHolderMC.startDrag(false, bounds);
```

Comment: Hi, I know how to do this.. the question asked how to limit the dragging target to the edges of the stage. I.E they cannot be dragged beyond **0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight** so that it always has content inside it instead of blank space.

Comment: Rectangle( 0,0,stage.stageWidth-imageDraggable.width,stage.stageHeight-imageDraggable.height)

Comment: Sorry, a better way to explain this would be that top and left are only allowed to be minus figures (outside the stage) and the bottom and right are only allowed outside of the stages dimensions. Sorry just saw your answer, I will try that.

Comment: Hi, that limited the top and left sides but I can still drag the bottom and right edges into the stage, leaving the undesired empty space

Comment: Can you define empty space? The rectangle creates a bounding box for the 0,0 point of the images movement.

Comment: Another factor here is if the image is inside a movieClip and is imageDraggable the image or the movieClip if it is the movieClip then the image will have to have the x,y set to 0,0

Comment: Hi, when I say empty space I mean the edge of the image is visible when it should be bound to the edges of the stage. The image is inside a MovieClip which has the coordinates of 0, 0 already (I thought I might be able to bound that but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3381/discussion-between-dave-mackintosh-and-the-asman)

Comment: Your edit is exactly the same, thus giving me the exact same result. Top and left work great. Bottom and right are still entering the stage (leaving blank space)

Comment: I posted some good samples of this in the chat room. Did you see them?